# How to interpolate in 3-D non-euclidean space?

Tags: interpolation, na.numerical-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

Assume, one has a 3-D non-euclidean space of points $p_i = \left(x_i, y_i, z_i\right) \in \mathcal{R}^2 \times \mathcal{R}_{> 0}$ with the following "distance" function $d\left(p_1, p_2\right) = \log \left( \frac{\frac{z_1}{z_2} + \frac{z_2}{z_1}}{2} \right) + \frac{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}{2(z_1^2 + z_2^2)}$ that does not satisfy the triangle law. So step $\Delta r$ in $xy$-plane is not interchangable with step $\Delta z = \Delta r$ in z-direction.

Further, some table $T$ of points like $(p_i, g(p_i))$, where $g$ is a parabolic function (a function that is at most quadratic in the $x,y,z$ coordinates), is given. How can I find a maximum of $g$ given table $T$ with respect to "distance" function $d$?

Thank you!

Comment: By 'parabolic function' do you mean a function that is at most quadratic in the $xyz$ coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I do. I put a corresponding note to the question body.

Comment: I know what the 'maximum of $g$' would mean, but I don't know what 'maximum of $g$ given Table $T$ with respect to "distance" function $d$" means.  Why is the distance function needed to figure out the maximum of $g$?  If you have enough points in the table $T$, you can figure out the coefficients of $g$ as a quadratic polynomial in $x$, $y$, and $z$ and then you can compute the maximum in the usual way.  How is your distance function relevant?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I mean the following. Function $d$ captures the fact that step $\delta r$ in xy-plane and step $\delta z$ in z-direction are not interchangeable, equivalent. So I suffer from that. I do not know how to process further. How should I figure out the coefficients of $g$ in this case?

Comment: @spk: I do not understand your answer to Robert Bryant. As he said, the max of $g$ does not depend on any extra structure such as $d$. Given the title of the question I think your question in fact lacks some context (e.g. do you want to interpolate "naturally" outside the points tackled by $T$ and search the max of the extended function?)

Comment: @spk:  Well, this is probably naive, but when you write out $g$ as a quadratic polynomial in $x$, $y$, and $z$, it will have $10$ coefficients.  If you know the values $g(p_i)$ at $10$ points $p_i$ ($1\le i\le 10$) (chosen sufficiently generically so as not to lie on any quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^3$), then you'll be able to solve for those $10$ coefficients.  Once you know the coefficients, you know $g$ at any point, and then it's a standard problem in calculus to find the supremum of $g$ (if one exists) in the half space $z>0$.

Comment: Thank you! You are quite right at all. This is a standard maximization problem. I have recognized it badly. So this topic is off-topic :)